# Python httplib2 - Unable to get successful response

Tags: python, json, python-3.6, httplib2

### JSON data doesn't have a successful response but instead null reference

I'm trying to call an .NET API in cloud through Python httplib2 library.

Same call works fine from PostMan but it doesn't give me the data thru this library. If I change the content type to application/xml in PostMan, then I get this response there. I tried to tweak the headers in different possibilities comparing to PostMan. Nothing helped. I couldn't trace the calls through Fiddler yet (to compare with PostMan call) as I had to setup proxy. I have interfaced with this api through React with same header and body and it worked fine.

```
content_headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
url = ('http://XXXXX')
body_data = {
        "store": 123,
        "UPC": 4011
             }
h = httplib2.Http()
response, data = h.request(url, 'POST', body=urllib.parse.urlencode(body_data), headers=content_headers)
```

Response:

{'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'expires': '-1', 'server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0', 'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319', 'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET', 'date': 'Thu, 03 May 2018 18:09:57 GMT', 'content-length': '114', 'status': '200'}

Data:

{'ResultCode': -1000, 'ResultDescription': 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.', 'pludetails': None}

Comment: Try using `requests`, it's an awesome Python library. Your code would be: `resp = requests.post(url=url,json=body_data)` and extract the answer with `resp.json()`

Comment: I think you want to set request body to `json.dumps(body_data)`

Comment: After reviewing different responses elsewhere and changes, it wasn't successful and I started using Requests library instead of httplib2. I haven't had any problems with it so far.